# C++ sorting text

Tags: c++, algorithm

I was asked the following interview question:

If there are two string inputs what method can be used to print the letters the string inputs have in common. For example if the user
input:

> working
>
> soaked

output:

> ok

What is the best algorithm to solve the problem?

Comment: I would note that "best" is a bit ambiguous -- best in terms of lowest memory use, or fastest execution, or some other arbitrary constraint?

Comment: if it will be constrained to letters then two small loops will solve your problem.

Comment: fastest execution cdhowie

Comment: Does in common mean the same letter, the same position, or both?

Comment: Just applies to the same letter

Answer (score 12):

```
string a = "working";
string b = "soaked";
set<char> setA(a.begin(), a.end());
set<char> setB(b.begin(), b.end());

vector<char> common;
set_intersection(setA.begin(), setA.end(), setB.begin(), setB.end(),
                 back_inserter(common));

copy(common.begin(), common.end(), ostream_iterator<char>(cout));
```

In fact, if no further processing is needed on the intersection, can send it straight to `cout`:

```
set_intersection(setA.begin(), setA.end(), setB.begin(), setB.end(),
                 ostream_iterator<char>(cout));
```

Comment: If this gives the answer you want I would avoid the `set`s and just sort the strings: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9fbfa41f3cd8e42. The reason is that all the node based containers are _very_ expensive and you almost never need the functionality they offer over just sorting an `array`/`vector`/`string`.

Comment: In this case you need to remove the duplicate values from the strings (done in `set` by definition), but probably `set_intersection` already does it.

Comment: @ChronoTrigger Based on some quick research into `set_intersection`, it doesn't appear to guarantee that duplicates won't be written to the output iterator.

Comment: Here's the example with uniquing: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96d2c832152655be

Answer (score 4):

Your description isn't unambiguous but the way I read it you want to know what letters are the same including position.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
  std::string const a = "working";
  std::string const b = "soaked";

  for (int i = 0; i < std::min(a.size(), b.size()); ++i) {
    if (a[i] == b[i]) {
      std::cout << a[i];
    }
  }
}
```

Produces:

```
ok
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear from the original question, but in common to me means the same letter, not necessarily in the same position. For example, I think they'd want `ok` printed if the inputs were `ok` and `soaked`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it is english letters.

First I would use boolean array size of 26

```
bool array[26];
```

then make it true for each letter at index `(letter-'a') (for upper letter-'A')`

then for the second string do the same but this time cheking `array[index]==true`. if yes then add to common list;

Here is small test code:

```
 bool array[26];
  for(bool &arr:array )arr=false;
  char text1[]="working";
  char text2[]="soaked";
  char common[80]="";


  for(char x:text1){
    int m=x-'a'   ;
    if(m>=0 && m<26){
      array[m]   =true;
    }
  }
  int j=0;
  for(char x:text2){
    int m=x-'a'   ;
    if(m>=0 && m<26){
      if(array[m] ==true){
          common[j]=x;
          ++j;
           array[m]=false; //do not check again
      }

    }
  }
  common[j]='\0';
  printf("%s\n",common);
```

Answer (score 2):

You tagged your question as c++ and @Igor provided what I think it's the optimal solution for that problem. However, I'd like to contribute with a language-agnostic pseudo-code that solves the problem using the same technique as `std::set_intersection`:

```
input: string a, string c
output: string c with common letters

sort(a) // O(nlog(n))
sort(b) // O(mlog(m))
c = empty

i = 0
j = 0
// O(min(n,m))
while i < length(a) && j < length(b) do
  if a[i] == b[j]
    add(c, a[i])
    // increment indexes avoiding duplicates
    do i = i + 1 until a[i] != a[i-1] or i == length(a)
    do j = j + 1 until b[j] != b[j-1] or j == length(b)
  else if a[i] < b[j]
    i = binary_search from a[i+1] to a[end] for b[j]
  else
    j = binary_search from b[j+1] to b[end] for a[i]
  end 
end

// Total cost (nlog(n))
return c
```

Answer (score 2):

I would note that `set_intersection` can appply to any sorted collection, not just `std::set`. Instead of copying from the strings to sets, then doing `set_intersection`, I'd just sort the strings and do the `set_intersection` on them.

This has the advantage of working (what I'd interpret as) correctly in the presence of repeated letters.  E.g. given inputs of "wood" and "book" it would produce "oo" instead of just "o".

Answer (score 1):

I would probably approach it like this:

```
std::set<char> common_characters(std::string const & a, std::string const & b) {
    std::set<char> common;

    std::string const & smaller = (a.size() < b.size()) ? a : b;
    std::string const & larger  = (a.size() < b.size()) ? b : a;

    std::set<char> chars(smaller.begin(), smaller.end());

    for (char i : larger) {
        auto found = chars.find(i);

        if (found != chars.end()) {
            common.insert(*found);
        }
    }

    return common;
}
```

It's not as slick as using `set_intersection()` (as in Igor's answer) but it has lower memory complexity and could perform faster as well, depending on the particular input strings.

Answer (score 0):

A simple and efficient solution, which doesn't need to allocate any more memory (for sets), would be to sort both strings, and then scan through them in parallell, like in the merge step of mergesort. Here is an implementation in plain C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int charcmp(char *p, char *q) { return *p - *q; }

int main() {
    char a[] = "working";
    char b[] = "soaked";

    int al = strlen(a);
    int bl = strlen(b);

    qsort(a, al, 1, charcmp);
    qsort(b, bl, 1, charcmp);

    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (i < al && j < bl) {
        if      (a[i] == b[j]) { printf("%c", a[i]); i++; j++; }
        else if (a[i] < b[j])  {                     i++;      }
        else                   {                          j++; }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Of course, if the strings are as short as in the example, there is no point in sorting, just scan through one string and look up in the other. But this algorithm scales well with very big string (it's linearithmic, while the lookup version is quadratic).

Comment: What does qsort, al, bl, and charcmp mean

Comment: [qsort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/). al and bl are local variables, set to the lengths of the strings a and b. charcmp is a function defined in the code just above main, to use as the compare function for qsort.